# Youtube API Invalid Grant and Required parameter is missing: grant_type

Tags: curl, oauth, go, youtube-api

I'm having trouble authenticating with the Youtube API via OAuth. It gives me this error:

- "error" : "invalid_grant" for **CURL**
- "error" : "invalid_request",
  "error_description" : "Required parameter is missing: grant_type" for **GoLang**

This is my CURL code:

`curl -i -X POST "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token" \
    -F 'code=CODE_FROM_MY_USER' \
    -F 'client_id=MY_CLIENT_ID' \
    -F 'client_secret=MY_CLIENT_SECRET' \
    -F 'redirect_uri=http://localhost:8080/platform/youtubeCallback.html' \
    -F 'grant_type=authorization_code'`

This is my Go code and has been verified to work for the Soundcloud API.

```
func Auth(code string) err {
    v := url.Values{}
    v.Set("code", code)
    v.Set("client_id", "MY_CLIENT_ID")
    v.Set("client_secret", "MY_CLIENT_SECRET")
    v.Set("redirect_uri", "http://localhost:8080/platform/youtubeCallback.html")
    v.Set("grant_type", "authorization_code")

    params := strings.NewReader(v.Encode())

    req, err := http.NewRequest("POST", "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token", params)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    req.Header.Add("Accept", "application/json")

    resp, err := c.Client.Do(req)
    if err != nil || resp.StatusCode != 200 {
        return err
    }

    json.NewDecoder(resp.Body).Decode(&c.Token)

    return nil
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out you need to define the content type:

req.Header.Set("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")

Answer (score 1):

It also works if you create a `map[string][]string` and pass it to `url.Values` like:

```
namesToSend := map[string][]string{
  "firstname":{Bob}
}
values := url.Values{}
values = namesToSend
```

Then in the `.NewRequest()` you pass it like you passed the params.

```
req, err := http.NewRequest("POST", "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token", values)
if err != nil {
    return err
}
```